# Error in compiling asterisk with libsrtp

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, asterisk

I want to compile the asterisk with SRTP library but in configuring the asterisk code, I get this error:

```
checking for the ability of -lsrtp to be linked in a shared object... no
configure: WARNING: ***
configure: WARNING: *** libsrtp could not be linked as a shared object.
configure: WARNING: *** Try compiling libsrtp manually. Configure libsrtp
configure: WARNING: *** with ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=/usr
configure: WARNING: *** replacing /usr with the prefix of your choice.
configure: WARNING: *** After re-installing libsrtp
configure: WARNING: *** configure script.
configure: WARNING: ***
configure: WARNING: *** If you do not need SRTP support re-run configure
configure: WARNING: *** with the --without-srtp option.
```

Also this is the code that checks this rule:

```
if test "$PBX_SRTP" = "1";

then

    saved_libs="${LIBS}"
    saved_ldflags="${LDFLAGS}"
    LIBS="${LIBS} -lsrtp"
    LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -shared -fPIC"
    AC_MSG_CHECKING(for the ability of -lsrtp to be linked in a shared object)
    AC_LINK_IFELSE(
    [
        AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
            [#include <srtp/srtp.h>],
            [srtp_init();]
        )
    ],

    [ AC_MSG_RESULT(yes) ],
    [
        AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
        AC_MSG_NOTICE(***)
        AC_MSG_NOTICE(*** libsrtp could not be linked as a shared object)
        AC_MSG_NOTICE(*** try compiling libsrtp manually and configuring with)
        AC_MSG_NOTICE(*** ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=/usr)
        AC_MSG_NOTICE(*** replacing /usr with the prefix of your choice)
        exit 1
    ]
    )
    LIBS="${saved_libs}"
    LDFLAGS="${saved_ldflags}"
fi
```

Commit detail: https://reviewboard.asterisk.org/r/857/diff/

I try several prefixes for compiling the libsrtp code but I get the same result.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

The warning says that it can't link with libsrtp because libsrtp's code needs to be relocatable, just like a shared library, and it seems that you're compiling libsrtp as a *static* library, I'd do as it suggests and re-build **libsrtp** using:

```
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC
```

I've also tried that here and it worked, note that I've used the default prefix /use/local/lib when building libsrtp

```
./configure --with-srtp=/usr/local/lib
checking for srtp_init in -lsrtp... yes
checking srtp/srtp.h usability... yes
checking srtp/srtp.h presence... yes
checking for srtp/srtp.h... yes
checking for the ability of -lsrtp to be linked in a shared object... yes
```

Answer (score 6):

in SRTP folder:

```
make uninstall
make clean
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=/usr/local/lib
make
make runtest
make install
```

in Asterisk folder:

```
 cd ../../asterisk/asterisk-11.3.0/
./configure --with-srtp=/usr/local/lib
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Build script check for a simple call to `srtp_init()` to be compilable, in order to this be valid you should have a folder that contain `<srtp>` in the path of include files and created `.a` library in path of linker. So after creating `libsrtp` put your prefix in the linker path